# Why wrapping a generic function and awaiting it returns different type opposed to returning the value directly?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

### Issue

Given these types:

```
type SelectAndInclude = {
  select: any;
  include: any;
};
type HasSelect = {
  select: any;
};
type HasInclude = {
  include: any;
};

type CheckSelect<T, S, U> = T extends SelectAndInclude
  ? "Please either choose `select` or `include`"
  : T extends HasSelect
  ? U
  : T extends HasInclude
  ? U
  : S;

declare function findMany<T extends {select?: string, include?: string}>(args: T): CheckSelect<T, Promise<1>, Promise<2>>;
```

Why following functions have a different return type?

```
function wrapperWorking<T extends {select?: string, include?: string}>(args: T){
  // correct return type inferred here
  return findMany(args); 
}

async function wrapperNotWorking<T extends {select?: string, include?: string}>(args: T){
  // result is always 1, which is wrong, since args is generic and not known here
  // result should probably have the type:
  // "Please either choose `select` or `include`" | 1 | 2
  const result = await findMany(args); 
  return result;
}
```

They are essentially the same, but their return type is different.
Actual and expected result can be seen here:

```
async function main() {
  const isErrorText = await wrapperWorking({select:"foo",include: "bar"});
  const is1 = await wrapperWorking({});
  const is2 = await wrapperWorking({select: "foo"});
  const is2Too = await wrapperWorking({include: "bar"});

  const shouldBeErrorTextButIs1 = await wrapperNotWorking({select:"foo",include: "bar"});
  const is1Too = await wrapperNotWorking({});
  const shouldBe2ButIs1 = await wrapperNotWorking({select: "foo"});
  const shouldBe2TButIs1Too = await wrapperNotWorking({include: "bar"});
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/PTAEBsEsCMCcENYE8LwHYBNQApYFNw8A3dAF1HSwGdIBbABygDNI8t7FynYB7W0PAA9SeWGnjgIMBMgCUAKFJJ6eUAGUCeAMakAgpgCSaLeACuGVQF5QAb3mhQVTToBcFNEgDc90JGNmLN3QveQBfbyUVUAAJeCoNQh1QazsHJ0TSII9vcMVlVViqIxNzK1sfPxLA9xDcvKiAYQALbQBrBO1SAB4AFQAadQGAVQA%20ZNAegWE8TCp1Zz1Df1KfAH5QACIABUI41TxIUhbYUC0mnh4nUAADdM7r0B4T68qAvGuNnzdJoRFZmLiHR0a1AQy%20Eymfwwc0KxTeILBDjcam8DnkFhMiFUTFMxlIkB4aFALEwAFlgr1ITNobY7jpVm4qKRYH4AOYDV6lBmOZls0IjbCIVlUb6yNzNNpA7r9UBbXi0SBOLoARhGAzlfEVeC6ACYRiNvPIQKBTE4TuBKPIcXiCUSAO4IegqWAAdSerTZlN%201LmNjppG5TJZaHZvmWFkDvJD-MFsGFotSoHwpFMYmJfgw5I8seFshy8nkcSQxmJuJ0ttADvgTtEADkeKQ3bAPSGvdN-n6FpHg6HORHGVHWTGhSKJrJE1pCUyk3gqKZwORrPA7fBDumycEc1Q8z5k6mifg5wv84WqMWtKWbYTQLRV2hsLJyg5J2hp4qAKKwXiwHq-cbL1dyCrGtXXdNlsE7DIXA2JgLg2Po%20zwNwNmgRANlCHdnynchFWVf8VzXYDnSbFtWQgjDUVObDfCoHV8MAytHWIsCQwg-1kNgnh0MwqjXxw2ieguejCKY0QSPAmxEOQ1DYG4w0sL4xxznnDAACE8E-b9f2EVTTFIAwqDwpcCKA0TYHrRsWLIyDOmgzj4KkzYZLknwXzfQzBJ4YTTOrZ0LPE1ibAo1zqKoZTwDUvAdV0-TDO8xjfLrBsAus9jNns4KFOnMKeBU9SdR6GKDOVTz4qIpLLObCTHJQtDgtCIA)

### Additional Context

I wanted to wrap a libary function to do some actions before and after calling it, e.g.:

```
async function wrapFindMany<T extends {select?: string, include?: string}>(args: T){
  await doSomethingBefore(args); // (e.g. async validation, sanitizing)
  const result = await findMany(args);
  await doSomethingAfterwards(result); // (e.g. writing to a DB)
  return result;
}
```

Is there a way to acheive this without redeclaring the return type and doing hacky `any`/`unknown` casts?

Comment: Not related to your main question but what you want to do is some sort of cross cutting concern. Take a look at [Method Decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#method-decorators)

Comment: Can you decorate existing classes (imported from a library) or even objects? I also think doing something like: `@Before((args) => validateArgs(args)) @After((result) => save(result)) findMany.[...]`, breaks the readability and doesn't feel natural, especially if it gets more complicated. But I see your points, could make sense in other scenarios I guess.

Comment: I'm not quite sure but take a look at [Decorator Factories](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#decorator-factories). Maybe you can wrap your 3rd party library functions in your own wrapper function.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mpDEzm) meet your needs?  If so I'm happy to write up an answer; if not, please elaborate on the failing use case.  Note that "without redeclaring the return type and doing hacky casts" is probably not possible... well, you don't need `any` or `unknown` but you still need type assertions (btw the term "cast" is ambiguous and best avoided, so I'm saying "type assertion" here since that's what TS has)

Comment: Also, is there some reason why you don't just do [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3zOqN)?  A union of promise types seems to be fraught with peril, whereas a promise of union types would be just fine.  I have a hard time trying to imagine why one would prefer the former to the latter.  If you're okay switching, then this would be my suggestion because it behaves much better.  Let me know.

Comment: One more thing: since your issue depends heavily on the call signature for `findMany()`, you should include that in the text of your question; a playground link is awesome but should only be supplementary (if someone can't click on that external link they should still have all the info they need to answer the question).

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for pointing out, I added `findMany` type to the question now. Unfortunately the types used for and `findMany` itself are generated by the library I use (https://www.npmjs.com/package/prisma). So I can't change any type, but agree that a union of promise types isn't ideal. I really would like the return type to be inferred since the library exports more functions like `findMany` (e.g `update`) with even more complex return types. I really just want to wrap that function, without redeclaring every single type again and was hoping that TypeScript inference could handle it somehow.

Comment: @jcalz another problem is that the library doesn't export the types used for the return type (e.g. `CheckSelect` here). The extensibility of the library is a known issue (github) for quite few months now. But I tried to wrap functions that the library returns, so I can extend their functionality without chaning it's typesafe API.

Comment: So then it seems like the answer is "no you can't do what you want".  I'm not particularly inclined to write up an answer if that's the takeaway, other than to point to the github issue you opened about this and say that any canonical answer will come from there.  But you might as well write that up yourself.